# Regex not matching digit

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to validate data with php. I just want the input to be numbers only. I have tried every variation and cannot get it to work. Is there something I am missing? It will keep returning false.

This is a simplified version of the code I am using.

```
$text1 = $_POST['textbox1'];
function textBox()
{
     $regexp="/^[0-9]+$/";
     if (preg_match($regexp, $text1))
     {
        return TRUE;
     }
     else
     {
        echo'<script type="text/javascript">alert("enter a valid  number.")</script>';
        return FALSE;
     }
}
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    if (! textBox())
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
     else
    {
        echo'<script type="text/javascript">alert("well done")</script>';
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

*Ok, I've made some horrible mess of my (previously working) code.. Yes you are all correct.. it's my  variables.. sorry guys and thnx for your help*

Comment: What about remove `^` or/and `$` from your regExp ?

Comment: I wonder Why dont you use the built in function `is_numeric()`

Comment: You need to read up about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: @Skippy It does because the variable $text1 is out of scope inside your textBox() function.

Comment: @Skippy It seems there are some problems with SO and all other subsites. Meanwhile take a look at [this](http://pastebin.com/qjTxA3uw)

Comment: 1. You are setting the value of `$text1` outside your function, which is not accessible inside unless you use global. How that works on your second example is a mystery, unless your example was incorrect.  2. Does the number submitted by the `$_POST` contain extra space or non-numbers? Try `echo`ing the texts within `$_POST['textbox1']` before calling the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex is correct. But you are checking `$text1` which does not exist in your function context. Pass it as a parameter.

Another option is to use `global` keyword to refer to `$text1` if it was not passed as an argument. It causes side-effect, so I strongly recommend not to do that way.

Yet another option (similar to using `global` keyword) is to refer to superblobal array `$GLOBALS` - same as `global`, this is a bad practice.

Comment: It would also be useful if you explained the other option i.e. `global`

Comment: @Skippy Example code is hard to provide help with if not the same as your active code - please post your real code and just remove unimportant lines and obfuscate any personal data

Comment: No, my principles do not allow me to use `global` keyword :) It is an option, yes, but it is a bad practice.

Comment: @Skippy let me guess: you example with no-parameters-passing works due to `register_globals` is enabled?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem does not come from your regex but from your `$text1` variable that is not in the scope of your function. It does not know where `$text1` comes from and so your validation messes up.
You should pass it as a parameter to your function or have somewhere in a global variable (less elegant) and it should work properly.

However, you should consider using functions such as [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) or [`is_int`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) to do the job rather than relying on a regex to do it.
This should be much more efficient and a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

### The Regex isn't the problem

Your regex works, so your problem lies elsewhere, as shown by this sample program:

```
$regex = "/^[0-9]+$/";
$input = "100";
preg_match($regex, $input, $matches);
echo var_dump($matches);
```

([Demo](https://eval.in/41896))

Without your full code, it's impossible to know what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
if(! textBox($text1)){
 ...
}
```

or this:

```
function textBox()
{
 global $text1;
 ...
}
```

otherwise your function textBox() has no access to the variable $text1

Comment: Don't use globals, that's why we have function parameters :)